# OpenGl 4, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER doesnt send normals data correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have a plain that is created using this method: [Heres an image showing my way of thinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmQC2.jpg)

I separate these stripes of triangles so that each one can have unique color and I still am able to use Vertex Indexing.

My problem is whit normals buffer. I create normals like this (this is in the algorithm that calculates vertices):

```
//Calculating Vertices
    for (unsigned int z = 0; z < m_size; z++)
    {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x <= m_size; x++)
        {
            Vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(m_startingPos.x + x * m_sqrWidth, m_startingPos.y, m_startingPos.z + z * m_sqrWidth));
            Vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(m_startingPos.x + x * m_sqrWidth, m_startingPos.y, m_startingPos.z + (z + 1) * m_sqrWidth));


            glm::vec3 TL = glm::vec3(m_startingPos.x + x * m_sqrWidth, m_startingPos.y, m_startingPos.z + z * m_sqrWidth);
            glm::vec3 TR = glm::vec3(m_startingPos.x + (x + 1) * m_sqrWidth, m_startingPos.y, m_startingPos.z + z * m_sqrWidth);
            glm::vec3 BL = glm::vec3(m_startingPos.x + x * m_sqrWidth, m_startingPos.y, m_startingPos.z + (z + 1) * m_sqrWidth);
            glm::vec3 BR = glm::vec3(m_startingPos.x + (x + 1) * m_sqrWidth, m_startingPos.y, m_startingPos.z + (z + 1) * m_sqrWidth);

            //Normals:
            Normals.push_back(glm::normalize(glm::cross(TL - BR, BL - BR)));
            Normals.push_back(glm::normalize(glm::cross(TR - BR, TL - BR))); 

            //Color:
            colors.push_back(0.0f); colors.push_back(0.0f); colors.push_back(0.5f);
            colors.push_back(0.0f); colors.push_back(0.5f); colors.push_back(0.0f);
        }
    }
```

So every normal is 0 1 0, I know this.

Here I create a buffer and attribPointer for normals (Its all in a class so unsigned int normalsBuffer is declared in .h file and initialised as NULL):

```
glGenBuffers(1, &normalsBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalsBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Normals.size() * sizeof(float) * 3, &Normals[0].x, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

In glVertexAttribPointer inedex is set to 2 because vertices take 0 and colors take 1.

So now heres my shader:

```
#shader vertex
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color_in;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 normals_in;

uniform mat4 u_MVP;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 color_f;

void main()
{
    color_f = color_in;
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0));
    Normal = normals_in;
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * normals_in;

    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);
};

#shader fragment
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;

in flat vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;

in flat vec3 color_f;

uniform vec4 u_Color;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform vec3 lightColor;


void main()
{
    vec3 objectColor = color_f;

    // ambient
    float ambientStrength = 0.1;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;

    // diffuse 
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;

    // specular
    float specularStrength = 0.5;
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), 32);
    vec3 specular = specularStrength * spec * lightColor;

    vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse + specular) * objectColor;
    color = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

[Heres an example how object with same shader works and how my plain behaves, It totally lacks diffuse lighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZe7D.gif)

If I go to the fragment shader and set vec3 norm = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0) it all works fine but thats not the way I want to do it.

So I send color data the same way and its fine but sending normals data doesnt seem to be working.

[Heres how it looks like when I got to fragment shader and set norm to 0 1 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VheLC.gif)

Comment: It is a simple typographic error. The attribute location of the normal vectors is 2. So it has to be `glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)` rather than  `glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I was losing my mind over it, since yesterday and it was so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

so you enable the VertexAttribArray for the color ( 1 )
you should activate the VertexAttribArray for the normals ( 2 ) and also
make sure you got the `(void*)0` correct if you are using a struct make sure to
use offsetof it is more reliable especially if you use compiler with optimizations